# I need redux-form component to select one of several

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Imagine a page where you are asked to choose your favorite sport.
But the sports are not listed in the drop-down list, but in the form of grids div.

You can choose only one sport. And the choice should be stored in redux-form store.

What components of redux-form can I use? 
Maybe there are ready-made solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can achieve what you're looking for by using a group of checkboxes. Simply style the label attribute with CSS and hide the checkbox.